# How to stack a div below a relatively positioned div?

Tags: html, css

I have an image slideshow that is positioned relatively (images within that container are positioned absolutely. For some reason, my divs below are not stacking vertically properly. 
In the code below, I'd like everything in my #wrapper div to go below the .images, but for some reason it is stacking behind it with overlap.

HTML:

```
<div class="images">
    <ul id="slideshow">
        <li><img src="" class="slide" alt="first"/></li>
        <li><img src="" class="slide" alt="second"/></li>
    </ul>   
</div> 
<div id="wrapper">
    <section class="text">
            <h1>text</h1>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow {
    position:relative;
}

#slideshow img {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're positioning the images absolutely. Try adding some height to your #slideshow

```
#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height: [height of image in pixels]px;
}

#slideshow img {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: yep, i've got height: 600px; to #slideshow img but didnt think that was relevant. even if i get rid of all positioning properties or try using float/clear, the div #wrapper and div .images are stacked on top of each other

Comment: ah I had another height property under #slideshow that was half the size. after adjusting, IT WORKED! ty

Answer (score 0):

```
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;  /*height of img*/
    list-style: none;
}
ul#slideshow li{
    display: block;
    height: 120px;
}
#slideshow img {
    position:absolute;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    display: block;
}
```